# Magento Store Switcher Not Working?

Tags: magento, cookies

I have a magento store with 2 languages. The language switcher works with set a different store view in the url.

```
/shop/?___store=english (for main language)
/shop/?___store=spanish (for 2nd language)
```

That works fine and how it should work. Now first problem comes when I am in Spanish Store and switch to main language with `www.mystore.com/?___store=english`, now I see the shop in the main language, but when I call `www.mystore.com/` without any storeview parameters it switches back to Spanish. Please let me know what I did wrong?

I am assuming it might be a issue with the cookies.

My current "Session Cookie Management" set up is the following:

```
Cookie Lifetime: 3631
Cookie Path: / 
Cookie Domain: .mydomain.com
Use Http Only: Yes
Cookie Restriction Mode: No.
```

Please let me know if there's a fix. Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add this js code in magento:

```
require([ 'jquery' ], function ($) { $(document).ready(function() { $(".switcher-option a").each(function(i, val){ var href=$(this).attr("href"); $(this).attr("dhref",href); $(this).removeAttr("href"); }); $(document).on("click",".switcher-option a", function() { var dhref=$(this).attr("dhref"); $.ajax({ url: dhref, success: function(data) { location.reload(); } }); }); }); });
```

Comment: require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".switcher-option a").each(function(i, val){
       var href=$(this).attr("href");
       
      $(this).attr("dhref",href);
       $(this).removeAttr("href");
    });


       $(document).on("click",".switcher-option a", function() {
 
   var dhref=$(this).attr("dhref");

 $.ajax({           
            url: dhref,           
          success: function(data) {
              location.reload();
            }
        });


       });


    });
});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Go to Manage stores settings @ backend and check the default language. Your default language must have been set to Spanish.